# Creating nested elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am little confused here. I would like to have this structure.

```
<ul class="cont">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=my_video_id" title="My title">
            <img alt="my alt" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/my_video_id/default.jpg" <="" a="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I did that using,

```
list_data += '<li><a href="' + url + '" title="' 
        + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' 
        + thumb + '"</a></li>';
```

As I wanted to escape the title (and description which I avoided here for an abstract view of the problem), I tried to do it the jQuery way. ie,

```
    $('<img/>').attr({
        alt: feedTitle,
        src: thumb
    }).wrap('<a/>').attr({
        id: 'id_' + videoID,
        href: url,
        title: description,
        rel: 'external'
    }).wrap('<li/>').attr({
        class: 'video'
    }).appendTo(".cont");
```

This is not working. I am doing something very very wrong. How to correct this?
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/e54VX/

Comment: By "the jQuery way" do you mean _chaining_? That's by no means exclusive to jQuery, & by no means "the way."

Comment: I don't know what your expected result is, but the jsFiddle seems to work fine for me, displaying what seems to be a list of thumbnails

Comment: @GrantThomas: jquery way of creating elements using `attr`. @Bartitude: the expected HTML has been posted on the top of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) for `wrap`:

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

You will need to call `.parent()` after each `wrap` if you want to work with the outer element instead of the inner.

```
$('<img/>').attr({
    alt: feedTitle,
    src: thumb
}).wrap('<a/>').parent().attr({
    id: 'id_' + videoID,
    href: url,
    title: description,
    rel: 'external'
}).wrap('<li/>').parent().attr({
    class: 'video'
}).appendTo(".cont");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e54VX/7/

Comment: thanks dude... sorry that i did not read the docs properly... still reeling from angularjs effect. thanks. may i ask, are there any simpler ways?

Comment: Just from a readability standpoint, I like to do it in reverse.  Instead of starting from inside and wrapping, I start with the outer and append inward.